# Maintaining two versions of same application and giving choice to user to switch between the two!

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I am trying to deploy a new version of a Java application (JSP/Servlet) deployed over tomcat. This newer version is in Beta as of now and hence, I want to give users choice to switch to the older version which is more stable.

What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: Could you provide _any_ more information about how the apps are deployed?

Comment: I am simply deploying a "war" file on tomcat server. The application is all JSP/Servlet kind of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your wars on two separate paths, but then configure Tomcat to redirect to one of them depending on user. You probably can use a cookie for that.

Comment: I could have two different "war" files. My question is on hitting the url say, "http://abc.com" how would i decide which one to pick? Also, how would i handle interaction between two "War" files.

Comment: Say one war sits on path /old/app and other war sits on /new/app. Deploy third war on /app and put a filter in it with logic to redirect to either /old/app or /new/app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that each application should be registered in server.xml under different URL. Now it is up to you how do you inform your users which URL is preffered. For example it could be

http://www.mycompany.com/myapp1/ 
or 
http://www.mycompany.com/myapp2/

From Tomcat's perspective these are 2 different applicaitons.

BTW to make things simpler you can just change the war file name, i.e. myapp1.war and myapp2.war. In this case just put these war files under /tomcat/webapps directory. They will be deployed automatically with URLs myapp1 and myapp2 respecively.

Comment: i do not want user to manually type in different urls. I want it to be transparent to the user.